# set min date with jqruery html5 native picker

Tags: html, jquery

i have problem to set min date attribute, on single page i have 25+ input type date for different products.
I can see value of attribute min is set to today date, but i can pick date before today(fields are not disabled)

```js
let today = new Date();
let dd = today.getDate();
let mm = today.getMonth() + 1;
let yyyy = today.getFullYear();
let dateList = $('.pickupdate');
let list = dateList.length;
let index = 0;
today = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;
for (index = 0; index < list; ++index) {
  let dateList2 = dateList[index];
  $(dateList2).attr('min', today);
  dateList[index];
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input 
  id="pickupdate" 
  type="date" 
  class="date-basic font-w-500 clr-white pickup m-0 datechk pickupdate" 
  name="pickupdate" 
  placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy"
  min="1899-01-01" max="" 
  value="{{$request->pickupdate}}" 
  required 
/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is due to the dateformat you're generating - `YYYY-M-D`. For it to work correctly it ***has*** to be `YYYY-MM-DD`. As such you need to include leading zeros in the day and month values, which can be easily done with a helper function.

Also note that I amended your logic to set the `attr()` on each date field. If you're using jQuery then use the `each()` method to loop over elements, not `for`. Also, the loop itself is redundant as jQuery will do it for you. Finally, if you have repeating HTML do not put `id` attributes on those elements as `id` have to be unique within the DOM.

With all that said, try this:

```js
let leadingZero = value => value.toString().padStart(2, '0').slice(-2);

let today = new Date();
let dd = leadingZero(today.getDate());
let mm = leadingZero(today.getMonth() + 1);
let yyyy = today.getFullYear();

$('.pickupdate').attr('min', `${yyyy}-${mm}-${dd}`);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="date" class="pickupdate" name="pickupdate" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" min="1899-01-01" max="" value="" required />
```

Comment: Or maybe a slightly more intuitive [`.padStart()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart) instead of the `.slice(-2)`: `value.toString().padStart(2, "0")`

Comment: @Andreas thank you! The amount of times I forget about `padStart()` is getting embarrassing :)

Comment: The `.slice(-2)` won't harm but is not necessary in this case.